# Using different orm.xml configurations in multi-module maven projects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I have a set of maven projects defined based on a layered architecture, as follows:

1- domain

```
-src/main/java
-src/main/resources/META-INF/
-src/test/java
-src/test/resources/META-INF/
```

2- repository (depending on domain)

```
-src/main/java
-src/main/resources/META-INF/
-src/test/java
-src/test/resources/spring/my-appcontext.xml
-src/test/resources/META-INF/orm.xml
```

My unit tests in repository layer make use of DbUnit in combination with hsql in-memory database. The persistence configuration is based on JPA/Hibernate, configured through spring. Below an example of the spring configuration I am using in my tests:

```xml
<!-- our datasource -->
<bean id="myDatasource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${datasource.driverClassName}" />
  <property name="url" value="${datasource.url}" />
  <property name="username" value="${datasource.username}" />
  <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- let hibernate be in between the database and JPA -->
<bean id="myJpaVendorAdapter"
   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
   <property name="database" value="${jpa.database}" />
   <property name="showSql" value="${jpa.showSql}" />
   <property name="generateDdl" value="${jpa.generateDdl}" />
   <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jpa.databasePlatform}" />
</bean>
<!-- entityManagerFactory - CONTAINER-managed -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="molecularanalysisDatasource"
      p:mappingResources="${jpa.orm}"
      p:packagesToScan="com.mypackages.domain">
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="myJpaVendorAdapter" />
      <property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.showSql">${hibernate.showSql}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.formatSql">${hibernate.formatSql}</prop>
      <prop key="dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${datasource.driverClass}</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${datasource.url}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${datasource.username}</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${datasource.password}</prop>
    </props>
      </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConfig"    
   class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseConfigBean">
   <property name="qualifiedTableNames" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConnection"
   class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="myDatasource" />
 <property name="databaseConfig" ref="dbUnitDatabaseConfig" />
 <property name="schema" value="${datasource.schema}" />
</bean>
```

The orm.xml I am using in the test scope makes sure that tables are created in hsqldb under the default catalog name PUBLIC. In other words using the orm.xml in test scope makes sure my tests do not care about specific catalog/schema names defined on domain entities, but just use the default one under hsqldb (This is because hsql allows only one Catalog, namely PUBLIC) when creating the tables during testing.

When I run my tests using Eclipse, the orm.xml under "src/test/resources/META-INF/orm.xml" can be found and is used by the entitymanagerfactory to create the tables in hsqldb.
However, if I run the tests using maven, the orm.xml is not picked up and as a result the entitymanager tries to creates my tables (entities) using the real catalog and schema names, which will fail in hsqldb since it only has one catalog, namely PUBLIC.

After enabling debugging in spring I noticed that the reason for this is because entitymanagerfactory uses a different "root Url" to search for configuration files when configuring the Jpa/Hibernate and persistence objects.

In case of running tests through Eclipse, entity manager uses the "target/test-classes/" directory where the META-INF/orm.xml can be found. In case of running tests through Maven the entity manager uses the domain.jar, where the META-INF/orm.xml is not included (since this is only defined in tests within integration module). Below the debug info:

1- Running tests through Eclipse:

```
 [main] DEBUG - Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    persistence provider classname: null
    classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@35a16869
    Temporary classloader:
        org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleThrowawayClassLoader@706f2039
         excludeUnlistedClasses: true
         JTA datasource: null
         Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
         PU root URL: file:/C:/DEVELOPMENT/project/integration/test-classes/
         Shared Cache Mode: UNSPECIFIED
         Validation Mode: AUTO
         Jar files URLs []
```

2- Running tests through Maven:

```
[main] DEBUG - Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
   name: default
    persistence provider classname: null
    classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@35a16869
    Temporary classloader:
    org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleThrowawayClassLoader@706f2039
    excludeUnlistedClasses: true
    JTA datasource: null
    Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
    PU root URL: file:/C:/DEVELOPMENT/project/maven-repository/domain/domain.jar
    Shared Cache Mode: UNSPECIFIED
    Validation Mode: AUTO
    Jar files URLs []
```

What I am not able to get working is how to make entitymanager include the META-INF/orm.xml when scanning for orm.xml file. Does anyone know how this can be done in Maven in testing? Adding this orm.xml to domain (src/main/resources/META-INF) will not help since this setting should only be used in test context.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?